# BigCommerce cart api: get options per line_item

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to get cart options to be included in the line item response

## My Attempt (nodejs)

`` return bc_acc.get(`/carts/${cartId}?include=options`, {include:'options'}).then(data => {.. ``

The response is fine but i expected to see options per line item. But its not there. The [API Docs show it in the response.](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/#/reference/cart/server-to-server-cart/get-a-cart)
[image]

## The Response

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the full path of the include object like:

`/carts/${cartId}?include=line_items.physical_items.options`